# Почему без условия IF работает, а с ним - нет? PHP

Tags: php, html, html-form

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Hobby </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="p2.php" method="POST">

<?php 
$sum = 0;
if($_POST['hunt']=="on")
{
 echo "Принадлежности для охоты<br>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h1'> Охотничье Ружьё - 9000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h2'> Капкан - 1500р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h3'> Охотничий лук - 3000р<br/>";
}
if($_POST['fish']=="on")
{
 echo "Принадлежности для рыбалки<br>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='f1'> Удочка - 1000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='f2'> Спиннинг - 3000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='f3'> Набор наживок - 350р<br/>";
}
if($_POST['games']=="on")
{
 echo "Принадлежности для компьютерных игр<br>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h1'> Геймпад 2000р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h2'> Игровая клавиатура 3500р<br/>";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='h3'> Игровая мышь 2500р<br/>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Выбрать'><br>";
              
echo "<br/><a href=main.php> На главную</a><br/>";

?>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

В первом документе вставлена маленькая форма HTML.

```html
     <form action="p1.php" method="POST">
    <select size="3">
      <option type="checkbox" name="hunt"> Охота </option>
      <option type="checkbox" name="fish" >Рыбалка </option>
      <option type="checkbox" name="games" > Компьютерные игры </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Выбрать">
        </form>
```

Comment: В массив `$_POST` загляните. Там у вас точно нет значений `on` у элементов.

Comment: И про `option` почитайте http://htmlbook.ru/html/option с `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select size="3" name="category">
  <option type="checkbox" value="hunt">Охота</option>
  <option type="checkbox" value="fish">Рыбалка</option>
  <option type="checkbox" value="games">Компьютерные игры</option>
</select>
```

```
if($_POST['category']=='hunt')
```